# Скрипт для игры Friday Night Funkin

Tags: python, циклы, клавиатура, бот

Сделал скрипт для автоматического нажатия клавиш в игре Friday Night Funkin, во время когда ничего не нужно нажимать скорость скрипта примерно 0.001, но во время нажатия падает до 0.3, это из-за pydirectinput, есть keyboard, с ним скорость падает до 0.1 что мне бы подошло, но нажатия с keyboard или любого другого плагина кроме pydirectinput не читаются игрой, подскажите, как можно ускорить мой код? (У меня экран 1680х1050, и координаты пикселей я ставил под свой монитор при развернутой игре (не на весь экран))

```
import pyautogui as pg
from time import time, sleep
import numpy as np
from mss import mss
import pydirectinput  as inp
import threading
import keyboard

while 1:
    def get_color_rgb(x,y):
        m = mss()
        monitor = {
            "left": x,
            "top": y,
            "width": 1,
            "height": 1,
        }
        img = m.grab(monitor)
        img_arr = np.array(img)
        item = img_arr[0][0]
        r = item[2]
        g = item[1]
        b = item[0]
        return [r, g, b]
    def check1(h):
        if h==[194,75,153]:
            inp.press('left')
    def check2(j):
        if j==[0,255,255]:
            inp.press('down')
    def check3(k):
        if k==[18,250,5]:
            inp.press('up')
    def check4(l):
        if l==[249,57,63]:
            inp.press('right')

    t1=threading.Thread(target = check1 ,args=(get_color_rgb(980,210),))
    t2=threading.Thread(target = check2 ,args=(get_color_rgb(1120,210),))
    t3=threading.Thread(target = check3 ,args=(get_color_rgb(1270,210),))
    t4=threading.Thread(target = check4 ,args=(get_color_rgb(1410,210),))

    ti1=time()
    t1.start()
    t2.start()
    t3.start()
    t4.start()
    t1.join()
    t2.join()
    t3.join()
    t4.join()
    ti2=time()
    print(ti2-ti1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Все решил, по итогу смог использовать модуль keyboard, но не через

```
keyboard.press_and_release('left')
```

а

```
keyboard.press('left')
time.sleep(0.05)
keyboard.release('left')
```

И так для всех 4 клавиш соответственно
По итогу проблема исчезает почти полностью
Оригинальную игру проходит на Харде без проблем, только 1 загвостка, код будет пропускать удержание клавиш там где это нужно, и когда я это исправлял код в целом становился очень медленным, ведь по сути количество операций возрастало вдвое, поэтому я решил что код не будет зажимать клавиши, ведь и так хорошо все проходит.